# Button for Hiding/blocking images in Chrome (like Opera has)

Tags: google-chrome, images, opera, google-chrome-extensions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to selectively load images in Chromium?](https://superuser.com/questions/263472/how-to-selectively-load-images-in-chromium)

Does anyone know of a Chrome extension that adds a toolbar button with the facility to disable images in the current tab? I'm looking to replicate the functionality that Opera has had since forever. I have searched the extensions site with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

**AdBlock:**

https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom

Specifically the **blacklist** feature:

http://code.google.com/p/adblockforchrome/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#How_do_I_blacklist_something?

(It does not need to be an ad to be blocked.)

Comment: This does not solve the problem. Adblock would block all images on all tabs, whereas I want to turn on/off image loading per tab, at will.

Comment: @James C, what about per-URL?

Comment: I can't find that exact functionality either. The only other thing I can suggest is Readability Redux: https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/jggheggpdocamneaacmfoipeehedigia But that removes more elements and styling than just the images.

Comment: Readability is interesting, but as you said it's not the same thing. I find it remarkable that only Opera have this as a feature!