# How to selectively load images in Chromium?

Tags: google-chrome, images, google-chrome-extensions, chromium

How to control loading of images individually like in Opera or in Firefox+ImgLikeOpera?

When I set "Don't load images" in options I don't see clear stubs to Ctrl+RightClick at them and allow *this* image *this* time to be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but the only ways for this to happen would be to have someone convert the firefox add-on into a chrome extension or to have someone make a chrome extension that does this from scratch. So you should ask the creator of the add-on to make a chrome version or ask someone who knows how to make extensions for chrome to do it.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [Chrome extension called Decreased Productivity](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/decreased-productivity/nlbpiflhmdcklcbihngeffpmoklbiooj?hl=en) that has a button in the address bar you click to hide all images. AFAIK you cannot selectively enable an image but the extension works really well and gives a clean, readable page.

Comment: The main reason was not to hide images, but save traffic by downloading only really required images.